# How to convert "Fri Jul 26 10:58:25 CEST 2019" to date?

Tags: r, timezone, as.date

How can I convert a string like "Fri Jul 26 10:58:25 CEST 2019" correctly to a date. The timezone are not the same every time.

```
as.Date("Fri Jul 26 10:58:25 CEST 2019", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S CEST %Y")
```

What is the correct placeholder for the timezone (CEST, CET, ...)? Or how can I ignore the timezone? It is not important for my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm confused by the question but if time zone isn't important then just omit it?

`as.Date("Fri Jul 26 10:58:25 2019", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")`

Or if you need it clearly specified

`as.Date("Fri Jul 26 10:58:25 2019", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", tz = "CEST")`

To remove the CEST using `gsub`:

`as.Date(gsub("(:[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]) ([[:alpha:]]*)", "\\1", x), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")`

Comment: I am guessing OP gets `"Fri Jul 26 10:58:25 CEST 2019"` as it is and it is not their choice to omit it or include it, it is already present in the data which they receive.

Comment: I get the Date String as described. I could delete the timezone with string functions, but I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: Ah in which case if it's always in that format use `sub` to remove the timezone

Comment: Just on top of my last comment here is the code to call `as.Date` on the string above after using `gsub` to remove the time-zone: `as.Date(gsub("(:[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]) ([[:alpha:]]*)", "\\1", x), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")`

Comment: That works. I though maybe there is a other was then string functions. However. Could you add this to your answer? Then I will accept it as the correct answer :)